# implementing iterators so I can sort a generic array cpp

Tags: c++, stl

**my question:**

so I want to implement an iterator just so I could sort this generic UniqueArray. 
I created a nested class inside the UniqueArray called UniqueArrayIterator. 
exactly which operators do I need to overload that are used in the sort algorithm in the STL?

** two more extra questions to further my understanding about iterators**:

(I'm aware that these extra questions are not reflected correctly on the title. I'm not used to posting questions on this site so please inform me if you think it's better for me to separate these to different questions and I'll edit this and do so.)

**about const_iterators**:
do I always have to define a const_iterator? can you give an example for overloading a conversion (forgot how it's called) operator from a non-const to a const iterator? anything I should avoid in defining a const iterator?
what's the best way, given a non_const Iterator class to define a const Iterator class and avoid code duplication?

**about making it easier to define nested iterator classes**:

**background**-
I've got an array of a set maximum size but I can remove and insert objects. in my implementation I've created a max size array that can have empty spaces. given an element I can access it's index. also, it doesn't matter that it has empty spaces because the set of indexes should not always be 1 to N. so it's perfectly viable.

the implementation should look like this:
(assume we're running on an inner array of Element* that can contain NULL values, and that our current location is index)

```
Element operator++() const{

    Element temp = *elements[index]
    while(!elements[index] && index < max_size) index++;
    return temp;
}
```

now, outside classes shouldn't be able to access what's in some "index". (this is part of the reason why I need an iterator). so I've made this class a friend. but the ++ operator depends on the values of the UniqueArray the iterator belongs to, so what bothers me is that I also have to keep a pointer to the UniqueArray it belongs to.

**the question** - 
if I'm defining an inner iterator class, and I basically want to use the outer class's values, is there any other way other than saving a pointer to your outer class? like in java where you can implement iterable and it changes relative to the current object?

Comment: See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator

Comment: Why don't you `typedef T* iterator;` instead?

Comment: I did that already, but thank you. it makes things simpler.

Comment: actually... trying to do that gives me segmentation fault for some reason.